# Calculate cost movement based on month and month slicer selection in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery

I want to calculate cost movement but the question is when the relative month slicer is set then the minimum date should have a base cost of £1.27 of Month 2021-01. This base cost is use to divide all other month to the maximum month of 2021-08.
For example, the movement from 2021-01 to 2021-02 is £1.25 divided by £1.27 = 99% and another example is movement from 2021-01 to 2021-02 will be £1.25 divided by £1.27 = 99% and for movement 2021-01 to 2021-03 is £1.27 divided by £1.27 = 100% and so on till movement from 2021-01 to 2021-08 will be £1.26 divided by £1.27 = 99.2%. How can I calculate this logic in Power BI (dax).

[image]

In excel it is easier as shown below:

[image]

Is this achievable?

Answer (score 0):

We need to calculate first dateInScoop using min and ALLSELECTED. Then we can calculate what is our first Cost in visible scoop. Last part is easy. We can do that this way:

```
movement = 
var __FirstDateInScoope = CALCULATE( min(Movment[Month]), ALLSELECTED(Movment) )
var __FirstCost = CALCULATE( sum(Movment[Cost]), TREATAS( {__FirstDateInScoope}, Movment[Month]), ALLSELECTED(Movment))
var __CurrentCost = CALCULATE(sum(Movment[Cost]))

return DIVIDE(__CurrentCost, __FirstCost)
```

[image]

Comment: I'm getting error message stating "A single value for movement cannot be determined. This can happen when a measure formula refers to a column that contains many values without specifying an aggregation such as min, max, count or sum to get a single result."

Comment: Are you sure that you correctly change the table/columns name? I have check this measure in test pbi and this work fine (check my update - screenshoot).

Comment: Month is from DateTable and Cost is from a FactTable, hence movement should be calculated used both tables.

Comment: I assumpt that you have relationship between this tables. Then change Movment[Month] to DateTable[Month] and Movment[Cost] to FactTable[Cost]

Comment: There is no movement table. Movement you see in screenshot is a measure